# How to change the format in the phone numbers column so that it has phone numbers in one format only

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet that includes a phone numbers column. Some of the entries are in this format "000-000-0000" and some are in this format "(000) 000-0000". I want to keep only one format. I've tried copy formatting also custom formatting but, nothing worked. TIA if you can please help me out.

Comment: Select the column and format it as text, then find and replace spaces, hyphens, `(`, and `)` with nothing. Then use custom format for a phone number.

Comment: @bugdrown tysm sir, your solution worked. Also, my bad for using the wrong tag it's removed now.

Comment: Sir, you are welcome. Go forth and do good in the world.